# Modifying HPE Proliant thermal settings

Tags: hp-proliant, ilo, settings, hpe

HPE states that from iLO 4 version 2.76 user can view and modify system thermal configuration settings using iLO interfaces. Finally! This is great feature for example those who have HPE incompatible drives. More details about this issue can be read from [here](http://dascomputerconsultants.com/HPCompaqServerDrives.htm)

However, they haven't documented feature and I can't figure out how settings should be modified. Any tips where to look?

Comment: You should use compatible disks. There's no reason not to.

But can you provide better information on the specific platform and hardware you're describing.

Comment: There is lot of reasons. This is my homelab and compatibe disk are quite expensive. Anyway, I have 6 HPE Proliant DL360p gen8 servers. Currently I have 15 unused Seagate Barracuda 2TB hard drives. I'd like to utilize those but because they messing with temperature sensor I can't.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to pages 180 and 185 in the iLO 4 User Guide

[Link to guide](https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docLocale=en_US&docId=c03334051)